# What's the best program (that you have used) to compile a professional windows help file (CHM)?

Tags: tools, windows-os, documentation

I have to make a help documentation in windows help file format. The amount of time I have got for this is ~ 5 hours and I have got about 50 pages (slides) that need to be added to this document.
So far I have tried using

```
Windows Help Workshop
```

Is there any other program that would help me compile chm in a quicker and perhaps more professional manner?

Comment: This question doesn't really belong on this site, since you're asking about the tools to use, rather than the experience of your users.

Comment: I tried deleting it but I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend RoboHelp by Adobe.
http://www.adobe.com/au/products/robohelp.edu.html

Answer (score 1):

**Htm2Chm** does a fantastic job! It has a very easy-to-use interface, and plenty of customization options. Best of all, it's freeware. Give it a shot!

[Download Htm2Chm here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Authoring-tools/Help-e-book-creators/htm2chm.shtml)